# Start of day in a particular timezone

Tags: javascript, date-fns

How do I get the start of the day in a given timezone?

For example, if I had a date object `x` representing Jan 1 9pm GMT, then `x.startOfDayInTimeZone("Australia/Perth")` should be Jan 1 4pm GMT, as "Australia/Perth" is GMT+8 (so Jan 1 9pm GMT is Jan 2 5am Perth, and the start of day is Jan 2 midnight Perth which is Jan 1 4pm GMT).

I've already got the library `date-fns` and `date-fns-tz` installed so if I could do this using those libraries that would be preferred (but not essential).

Comment: I mean midnight